# Coordinate Conversion: Decimal Degree to Deg-Min-Sec of lat/long Coordinates

Tags: latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a tool to convert DD to DMS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10703/looking-for-a-tool-to-convert-dd-to-dms)

I have two sets of climatic lat/long point data in excel worksheets. One of them is in decimal degrees and another is in degrees/minutes/seconds. In order to integrate these 2 data to a set of excel data, first I need to change decimal degrees to deg/min/sec. Please help me how can I do this. What formula can be used to do this?

Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

1 degree = 60 minutes

1 minute = 60 seconds

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LatLong.aspx
Under Determining Degrees, Minutes, And Seconds 
*But* for degrees you'll want to floor (likely with a -1 significance if you're in the Western Hemisphere)