# Which system of units does the unit 'degree' belong to?

Tags: data, vector, latitude-longitude, units

Let us say that I would like to store latitudes and longitudes like this:

lat
35 degree

long
80 degree

Which system of units does the unit 'degree' belong to? It is not really a SI unit nor a Imperial unit ...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Units suggests degrees are derived from the SI derived unit Radians

Comment: First i removed, then added back the 'vector' tag back since a unit  vector *is* an alternate means of storing angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Degrees are part of a [modified Sexagesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal) (base 60) number system. Even though there are 360 degrees in a circle, 360 is 6 x 60. The origin of degrees as angular units is unclear (see [wiki/Degree_(angle)#History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)#History).)

See [Coordinate Conversion: Decimal Degree to Deg-Min-Sec of lat/long Coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/10619/3195)  for subdivisions of a degree.

In terms of *fundamental* physical units, mass, length and time, angles are actually *unitless* because they are derived from ratios of lengths:

For a sector: arc angle = arc length / radius

For a right triangle:  angle 
= arcsine (opposite / hypotenuse)
= arctan (opposite / adjacent)
= arccosine (adjacent / hypotenuse)

We still give a name to those natural unitless angles: *radians*.

2 π radians = 360 °

And, according to [wiki/International_System_of_Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) and [convertunits.com/type/angle](http://www.convertunits.com/type/angle), the radian is *derived* from SI base units.

For data storage, you can use *any* units, so long as you have proper conversions to/from those used in the interfaces. Radians are most readily suitable for trigonometric functions, but then, if you use [direction cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine), you can avoid some (costly) trigonometric functions.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to critique, please?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah radians are derived base units and unit less: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit